# Fix inconsistent route names (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.2

#### Routes

```
resources :favorites, only: [ :index, :create, :destroy ] , param: :listing_id
```

#### Rake routes

```
favorites GET    /favorites(.:format)             favorites#index
favorites POST   /favorites(.:format)             favorites#create
favorite DELETE /favorites/:listing_id(.:format)  favorites#destroy
```

Notice the (s) in favorites, why is it not all favorite or favorites?

I create one favorite and destroy one favorite, so I think it should be singular in both.

I need

```
favorite POST   /favorites/:listing_id(.:format)       favorites#create
```

I tried this in my routes:

```
resources :favorites, only: [ :index, :destroy
 ] , param: :listing_id 

post 'favorites/:listing_id' => 'favorite#create', as: :favorite
```

but get this error:

> ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'favorite'  You may
>   have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or
>   you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the
>   same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with
>   `resources` as explained here: 
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

How do I modify this one?

#### How do I keep it consistent as I need create path and destroy path consistent in my view for a number of reasons.

#### My controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_listing, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    @favorites = current_user.favorites.map{|i| i.id} || []
    @listings = ListingsQuery::Search.call(:favorited_ids=>  current_user.favorites.map{|i| i.id} )

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
    end
  end

   def create
    if current_user.favorite!(@listing)
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user.unfavorite!(@listing)
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  private 

  def load_listing
    @listing_id = favorite_params[:listing_id]
    @listing = Listing.find(@listing_id)
  end

  def favorite_params
    params.permit(:listing_id)
  end

end
```

### view

```
<% if listing.is_favorited == true  %>

  <%= link_to favorite_path(:listing_id => listing.listing_id), method: :delete, remote: true do%>
      <i id='i-<%= listing.listing_id %>' class=" fa fa-heart"></i>
    <% end %>

  <% else %>

  <%= link_to favorite_path(:listing_id => listing.listing_id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <i id='i-<%= listing.listing_id %>' class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

### create.js

```
(function(){
  $("#i-<%= @listing_id %>").removeClass('fa-heart-o');
  $("#i-<%= @listing_id %>").addClass('fa-heart');
  $("#i-<%= @listing_id %>").parent().attr("data-method",'delete');

})();
```

#### Why is this...

```
resources :favorite do
  collection do
    post "for_lisiting/:listing_id", action: :create_for_listing
    delete "for_listing/:listing_id", action: :delete_for_listing
  end
end
```

preferred over this..

```
 match 'favorite' => 'favorites#create', via: :post
 match  'favorite' => 'favorites#destroy', via: :delete
```

It seems to me, but maybe I am wrong. that

```
/favorite/for_lisiting/:listing_id(.:format)
```

is unnecessarily long compared to

```
/favorite/:listing_id(.:format)
```

however, I am a novice, so value your reasoning.

Comment: What is annoying you about this?

Comment: For the create and destroy, why would I have favorites and favorite? I create one favorite and destroy one favorite. so I think they should be singular?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html You can change this any way you want to with some configuration. I however would recommend not fighting convention too much in Rails.

Comment: I don't think this is an inconsistence, it's that way by design (yes, you are creating one favorite, but the route is not `favorite_path(favorite)` since you don't have a favorite yet). You can change that, but it's just a convention, I bet it was already discused long time ago when rails started, but I wouldn't know where to look for that to read de proper arguments. I wouldn't fight the convention.

Comment: @arieljuod, please look at above, I updated. thanks

Comment: You have to use something different for `as: :favorite` `as: :my_favorite` maybe. Then in your views `my_favorite_path(....)`

Comment: @Iceman, I think I am not being clear, I need the same exact path name. favorite_path(:listing_id = 2), for post and delete methods, I also did not define the create action in resources, so not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Where does `listing_id` come from if you don't have an ID yet? Is that another model? If you have a `Listing` model then you may want to do something like `listings/:listing_id/favorite` which would require a different setup, is that what you need?

Comment: @arieljuod, it's not the favorite id, it's a parameter I need to create the favorite. I am favoriting a listing.

Comment: Ok, I get it, you see it as an inconsistence because you are not following REST principles, I'll add an answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using rails `resource` helper, it creates some REST endpoints. You have listings that can be favorited, you are mixing both resources. Your resource is the Listing and favorite/unfavorite/favorites are actions on the resource.

Try something like this:

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    post :favorite, action: :create_favorite
    delete :favorite, action: :delete_favorite
    get :favorites
  end
end
```

That will give you two route: `/listings/:id/favorite` (both for create -POST- and delete -DELETE-) and `/listings/:id/favorites` (GET). Both create and delete will be the same `favorite_listing_path(listing)` (or similar, check `rake routes`).

Now, on your ListingsController, define those actions:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def create_favorite
    Listing.find(:id).favorites.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to :something, notice: 'Favorited'
  end

  def delete_favorite
    Listing.find(id).favorites.where(user: current_user).destroy_all
    redirect_to :something, notice: 'Unfavorited'
  end

  def favorites
    @favorites = Listing.find(id).favorites
  end

  # of course, you could add a before_action to DRY it, I just wanted to be explicit on which is the actual resource
end
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, except I actually don't have a listings controller, not do I make listings, it's complex, and hard to explain. Listings is a related table of a normalized data structure, and not a resource in itself. How can I modify keep the nested structure, but not create listings resources that are independent of favorites?

Comment: Also, get favorites index returns all the favorites of a specific user, not favorites of a listing, but I get your point.

Comment: I updated added my controller for , and view, and create.js

Comment: You could use the Favorite as a resource but don't use the default create/delete actions routes, define something more explicit like: `post "for_lisiting/:listing_id", action: :create_for_listing` and `delete "for_listing/:listing_id", action: :delete_for_listing`. You'll have a route like `favorite_for_listing_path(listing_id)` pointing to FavoritesController.

Comment: Can you clarify as I posted above what I think you said.

Comment: My favorites controller is creating a favorite record, with a parameter of listing ID, and it is destroying a favorite record where a user_id =x and listing_id =y.

Comment: Sorry I didn't say this, use `collection do` instead of `member do`. The former does not add the `/:id` segment on the url. You may also need to add a name for one of the route, `post ".....", action: :create_for_listing, as: :favorite_for_listing` so you get the helper `favorite_for_listing_path`.

Comment: Got it, I updated based on comments, please review.

Comment: To respond to your last question. `favorites/:some_number` on a RESTful resource implies that `some_number` is the ID of one "Favorite" object. You can use that number as another thing like a `listing_id`, just know that you are moving out the conventions and may lead you to confusion later. `DELETE favorites/for_listing/1` is pretty clear on what it does (delete the favorite for the listing with listing_id 1), `DELETE favorites/1` means "delete the favorite with id 1" by convention. I prefer verbose and REST urls rather than saving some character.